# GAE ndb transaction write doesn't take retries into account

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore

I'm doing a transactional write to the datastore on GAE, which sometimes returns the following error:

```
TransactionFailedError: The transaction could not be committed. Please try again.
```

To automatically retry the transaction, I added the retries parameter to the function. So it looks as follows:

```
@ndb.transactional(retries=4)
  def myFunction():
    #code
```

But it doesn't seem to retry at all. If I manually restart the tasks it executes without issues. What is the recommended way of handling this?

Comment: Hey Vincent! As you see from the docs https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue, the "transactionFailedError" is returned after the retries. Might just be that the retries don't work. Maybe you're being rate-limited and the fact that when you retry manually it works is that you take long enough for the rate-limit to stop?

Comment: Thanks Patrice. I'm not sure what rate-limit could be in play, but it is a possible explanation. I've decided to move to daily statistics, instead of updating on every event. It solved the issue and will make the system more scalable anyway.

Comment: thanks for the quick upvote and accept :) I wanted to make sure the answer to your question wasn't hidden in the comments, but thank you anyway :) Enjoy the platform! If there's anything else, feel free to post here  (we monitor the site for good questions about the platform and answer them the best we can). If you have something not suited for Stack, you can always go to our issue tracker for Defect or Feature Requests (https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) or our Google Groups for more open-ended questions (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine)

Comment: Great, I'll add these to my resources. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue), you get that error message after all the transactions.

I know there are some short term "rate limits" that you can hit if you try the same thing too often. Possible that you've been hitting one of these (would explain why trying manually a little while later makes it go through).

In any case, as OP pointed out himself, pushing an update on every event is not extremely scalable. Moving to a longer update cycle (once a day, once a week, depending on traffic) might be a better solution here.